# Generics issue - inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)

Tags: java, generics

We currently have one class that won't compile with openjdk 6. The following shortened class reproduces this error:

```
public class Copy implements ICopy {        
    public <A,B extends List<A>,C extends Map<A,B>> A method(A a, B b) {
        A something = null;
        return something;
    }

    @Override
    public <A,B extends List<A>> A method2(A a, B b) {
        return method(a,b);
    }    
}
```

The interface is simple, it just shows, that we can't change the signature of the `method2`:

```
public interface ICopy {    
    public <A,B extends List<A>> A method2(A a, B b);
}
```

It compiles with oracles java versions and openjdk 7 - but fails with openjdk 6, and, unfortunatly, that's the version that we have to use to compile the (original) code.

The error message is

```
Copy.java:15: invalid inferred types for C; inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
inferred: java.util.Map<A,B>
bound(s): java.util.Map<A,B>
                return method(a,b);
                             ^
```

All I need are some ideas how to change the implementation of `method2` so that it would compile. I wouldn't even care about compiler warnings...

Comment: looks like a bug. Eclipse compiler and Sun's compiler don't say anything about this.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet - a bug or an overly strict handling of generic types of that java version. And, yes, eclipse doesn't complain (which made it quite complicated to reproduce this nasty error that kills the build).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would try specifying the bounds explicitly, like this:

```
return this.<A,B,Map<A,B>>method(a,b);
```

However, more generally, I don't see the need for the type parameter `C` at all.  None of `method`'s arguments or its return type references `C` at all, so if you can change the signature of `method`, I would just omit that type parameter entirely.

Comment: Ah, sorry, this is really a small sample class that simply focusses on the error. The *real* methods use all type parameters.